# Which of the three options is the most valuable?

Tags: options

Which of the following options is the most valuable?

- American vanilla call
- European vanilla call
- Bermudan call

No further assumptions given - that was an interview question and I ordered them followingly:

```
European call < American call < Bermudan call
```

as the last one has the most optionalities embedded.

Was this the correct answer/reasoning? What do you think?

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered if you feel my explanation is enough? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The greater the optionality, the greater the price. Hence, in your case:

- a European call "gives" you optionality on a single day;
- a Bermudan call "gives" you optionality on a series of days between the beginning of the contract and its maturity;
- an American call "gives" you optionality on all days between the beginning of the contract and its maturity.

Hence your answer is **not** correct $-$ thank you @Olaf:

$$ \textrm{American} \geq \textrm{Bermudan} \geq \textrm{European}$$

**PS**: Why do you think a Bermudean option has more optionality than an American one?

**PS2**: as precised by @LocalVolatility, the additional optionality might be worthless, hence the inequalities are not strict.

Comment: OP's ordering doesn't match yours.

Comment: Just to be precise: The inequalities should be weak. The additional optionality might be worthless.

Comment: @LocalVolatility When? :)

Comment: @Henrik I don't understand your comment. If you have a follow-up question then please open a new question.

Comment: @LocalVolatility My intuition is that the inequality is probably strict unless the underlying is behaving somehow degenerately, maybe you knew if that was the case. I don't think there is enough value in that observation to warrant a new question though.

Comment: Depends on what you call degenerate. Consider a non-dividend paying stock on a geometric Brownian motion asset and assume interest rates are non-negative. Then there is no value in the additional exercise rights given by Bermudan or American call options and all three prices agree.